# How to write an image on disk from blob?

Tags: java

I am tring to create an image file from database on disk. I wrote the following code:

```
{
    oracle.sql.BLOB blob1 = (BLOB) rs.getBlob(1);

    //fillFilePath is file path 
    File blobFile   = new File(fillFilePath);
    String checkExe[]=fillFilePath.split("\\.");

    FileOutputStream  outStream  = new FileOutputStream(blobFile); 
    InputStream inStream   = blob1.getBinaryStream(); 

    int length  = -1; 
    int size    = blob1.getBufferSize(); 
    byte[]  buffer  = new byte[size]; 

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( inStream );
    System.out.println("Inside image upload");

    System.out.println("Inside image jpg");
    ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", outStream);
```

But it is not working.

Please give me any suggestions?

Comment: What is in the blob? If it is a jpeg, then you don't need to use the ImageIO at all, but just write the bytes to disk.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
        BLOB image = ((OracleResultSet) rs).getBLOB("image");            
        blobLength = image.length();
        chunkSize = image.getChunkSize();
        binaryBuffer = new byte[chunkSize];

        for (position = 1; position <= blobLength; position += chunkSize) 
        {                               
            bytesRead = image.getBytes(position, chunkSize, binaryBuffer);               
            outputFileOutputStream.write(binaryBuffer, 0, bytesRead);                
            totbytesRead += bytesRead;
            totbytesWritten += bytesRead;
        }
```

Comment: I  tried  above code data write to image file but it not privew that image .

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedImage bi= ImageIO.read(obj.getPhoto().getBinaryStream());//photo  is Blob.
             File outputfile = new File("folderInYourProject\\"+nameVar+".jpg");
             ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", outputfile);
```